# Ubuntu 20.04 and OpenFortiGUI: VPN works but cannot access smb

Tags: 20.04, samba, vpn, openvpn, smb

I set up my VPN using OpenFortiGUI and it seems to work correctly since I can access the intranet of my institute. I am now trying to access a remote server (`smb://fs01.something.lan/`) from the `Files`. I insert my username, password (`Domain` is automatically se to `WORKGROUP`) and I click `Connect`. The problem is that when I do so, the same window pups up again and again. Using the same VPN details, I can connect to this server from my Mac without problems. Any suggestion?